# Same API requests, one gets response and stores it, the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

So I have two fetch requests from different API's. I don't understand why this one:

```
let [responseObj, setResponseObj] = useState({});
fetch(`https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather?units=${unit}&q=${uriEncodedCity}`, {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                if (response.cod !== 200) {
                    throw new Error()
                }

                setResponseObj(response);
                setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setError(true);
                setLoading(false);
                console.log(err.message);
            });
```

**gets AND stores** the response but this one doesn't:

```
let [geoObj, setGeoObj] = useState({});
    
fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${uriEncodedCity}&limit=1&appid=${Key}`, {
            "method": "GET"
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                if (response.cod !== 200) {
                    throw new Error()
                }
                setGeoObj(response);
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setError(true);
                setLoading(false);
                console.log(err.message);
            });
```

In this second request the api key works, in the network tab I get the json from the API but when I try to store it in the response and log it to the console it shows up blank while on the first one I get the json response.

Comment: Can you share the API responses for both requests? Perhaps one is already returning JSON and it doesn't need to be "extracted".

Comment: `setState` isn't syncronous you shouldn't console.log after a set, you must do it inside an `useEffect`

Comment: So the request that works returns this: https://pastebin.com/J8nrbEWf
while the request that doesn't work returns this: https://pastebin.com/Pakyw4BT
What I don't understand is why one request stores the response and the other doesn't

Comment: I was asking for the network response, not the JSON you think you are storing. I.E. what you see in the network tab. And also, what your code sees *before* `response.json()`.

Comment: Those are the network responses, I've copied them from the network tab. The only thing I did was format them before pasting to pastebin

Comment: I see. I don't see much issue in the code then. What is logged if you move the console log into the first `thenable`? Logged at each step?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because one of them is an array and you are trying to store it inside an object — look at `useState({})`.

I tried this code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sid-nyot2?file=/src/App.js) and it works fine.